# REQUESTS: Return file object from url (as with open('','rb') )

Tags: python, file, python-requests, download, pypdf

I want to download a file straight into memory using `requests` in order to pass it directly to `PyPDF2` reader avoiding writing it to disk, but I can't figure out how to pass it as a `file object`. Here's what I've tried:

```
import requests as req
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

r_file = req.get('http://www.location.come/somefile.pdf')
rs_file = req.get('http://www.location.come/somefile.pdf', stream=True)

with open('/location/somefile.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r_file.iter_content():
        f.write(chunk)

local_file = open('/location/somefile.pdf', 'rb')

#Works:
pdf = PdfFileReader(local_file)

#As expected, these don't work:
pdf = PdfFileReader(rs_file)
pdf = PdfFileReader(r_file)
pdf = PdfFileReader(rs_file.content)
pdf = PdfFileReader(r_file.content)
pdf = PdfFileReader(rs_file.raw)
pdf = PdfFileReader(r_file.raw)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Without having to know anything about `requests`, you can always make a file-like object out of anything you have in memory as a string using `StringIO`.

In particular:

- Python 2 `StringIO.StringIO(s)` is a binary file.
- Python 2 `cStringIO.StringIO(s)` is the same, but possibly more efficient.
- Python 3 `io.BytesIO(b)` is a binary file (constructed from `bytes`).
- Python 3 `io.StringIO(s)` is a Unicode text file.
- Python 2 `io.BytesIO(s)` is a binary file.
- Python 2 `io.StringIO(u)` is a Unicode text file (constructed from `unicode`).

(The first two are "binary" in the Python 2 sense--no line-ending conversion. The others are "binary" vs. "text" in the Python 3 sense--bytes vs. Unicode.)

So, `io.BytesIO(response.content)` gives you a valid binary file-like object in both Python 2 and Python 3. If you only care about Python 2, `cStringIO.StringIO(response.content)` may be more efficient.

Of course "file-like" only goes so far; if the library tries to, e.g., call the `fileno` method and start making C calls against the file descriptor it isn't going to work. But 99% of the time, this works.

Comment: Bumping this nice, succinct answer.  I wondered, @abarnert, is there a resource that might outline what file-like object methods are not available in StringIO objects?